# logrotate - backup any file

Tags: linux, server, logrotate

I have one file. It's not a log file. Every day I need to copy it somewhere else adding timestamp to its name. I need to keep last ten (10) days copies.
I am considering using logrotate service (server is running CentOS).

My question is if there is some limit on logrotate to rotate only log files or if I can use any other file and location. That is may I specify some other location where to put copies with timestamps and to hold only last 10 (days) copies?

Thanks in advance for your hints.

Comment: A log file is just a normal text file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rotate any file in any location e.g. take a look at `/etc/logrotate.d/samba` (if installed) which rotates `log.smbd`. Just create a new file in `/etc/logrotate.d/` and configure for your file to be rotated. A nice description is [here](http://linuxconfig.org/setting-up-logrotate-on-redhat-linux) for centOS not different ([here](https://abdussamad.com/archives/541-Log-rotation-in-CentOS-Linux.html)).

The problem is the timestamp in the name. If you want this it is no longer **rotating**. With `logrotate` the latest archived file is always number 1 and thus all older once are getting renamed. But they keep their time of last modification stored in the file system untouched. But this time is not in the name.

As an alternative you can just create a new `cron` job by adding a file in one of the `\etc\cron.*\` directories. This cron job can move you file adding a timestamp e.g. by using `date +%y%m%d_%H:%M` and create a new file using `touch`. No need for `logrotate`.

Comment: You can add timestamp to the filename by using `dateext` directive in a logrotate configuration file. More info on [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) man page.